# Python help: Paths in gmplot

Tags: python, path, polygon

I can’t find any documentation on using paths in gmplot.  I came up with this code which gets close, but it connects all of the lines and fills it in with a color - I don't want that.

I simply want a path like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUsPD.jpg

But, what I’m getting is this: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lveFT.jpg

Heres’s my code:

```
pathlon = -117.2974695,-117.2980671,-117.2984607,-117.2979182,-117.2974082,-117.2966604,-117.2977518,-117.2987498,-117.2981491,-117.297708,-117.2972804,-117.2965301,-117.2979485,-117.2975028,-117.2980506,-117.2982983,-117.2976609,-117.2970861,-117.2969908,-117.2981731,-117.2987695,-117.2981146,-117.2976909,-117.2969674,-117.2969299,-117.298394
pathlat = 33.27172039,33.27197757,33.27217535,33.27225324,33.27218351,33.27233921,33.27242614,33.27248971,33.27268346,33.27265944,33.27263664,33.27279608,33.27281652,33.27194103,33.27176546,33.27224514,33.27222714,33.27208829,33.27237357,33.27243373,33.27262189,33.27268296,33.27265933,33.27262125,33.27282274,33.27283925

gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(pathlat[0],pathlon[0],18)

gmap.polygon(pathlat,pathlon,edge_color="cyan", edge_width=5, face_color=None, face_alpha=None, clickable = False)

gmap.draw('map.html')
```

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using polygon, this is the expected consequence. You should use plot method.

Please see following part;

```
pathlon = -117.2974695,-117.2980671,-117.2984607,-117.2979182,-117.2974082,-117.2966604,-117.2977518,-117.2987498,-117.2981491,-117.297708,-117.2972804,-117.2965301,-117.2979485,-117.2975028,-117.2980506,-117.2982983,-117.2976609,-117.2970861,-117.2969908,-117.2981731,-117.2987695,-117.2981146,-117.2976909,-117.2969674,-117.2969299,-117.298394
pathlat = 33.27172039,33.27197757,33.27217535,33.27225324,33.27218351,33.27233921,33.27242614,33.27248971,33.27268346,33.27265944,33.27263664,33.27279608,33.27281652,33.27194103,33.27176546,33.27224514,33.27222714,33.27208829,33.27237357,33.27243373,33.27262189,33.27268296,33.27265933,33.27262125,33.27282274,33.27283925

gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(pathlat[0],pathlon[0],18)

gmap.plot(pathlat,pathlon,'cornflowerblue', edge_width=10)

gmap.draw('map.html')
```

Comment: Aha!  That is exactly what I needed.  Thank you, 
nuriselcuk !  I love this forum.